# Setting "Origin" and "Access-Control-Request-Method" headers with Jersey Client

Tags: jersey

Jersey client is not setting the "origin" header for me and I wonder if I am missing anything.

```
String origin="http://www.localhost.com";
ClientResponse response= webResourceBuilder("my/endpoint")
            .header( "origin" , origin)
            .header("Access-Control-Request-Method", "POST")
            .header("xorigin", origin)
            .header("whatever", "test")
            .accept("application/xml")
            .get(ClientResponse.class);
```

When I inspect at runtime the request headers on the server side, I find "xorigin" and "whatever" headers, but not "origin" and "Access-Control-Request-Method"

How can I set these headers?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Default Jersey client uses [HttpURLConnection](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java#HttpURLConnection) to send requests to the server. `HttpUrlConnection` restricts some headers to be sent in a request, see:

```java
/*
 * Restrict setting of request headers through the public api
 * consistent with JavaScript XMLHttpRequest2 with a few
 * exceptions. Disallowed headers are silently ignored for
 * backwards compatibility reasons rather than throwing a
 * SecurityException. For example, some applets set the
 * Host header since old JREs did not implement HTTP 1.1.
 * Additionally, any header starting with Sec- is
 * disallowed.
 *
 * The following headers are allowed for historical reasons:
 *
 * Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Cookie, Cookie2, Date,
 * Referer, TE, User-Agent, headers beginning with Proxy-.
 *
 * The following headers are allowed in a limited form:
 *
 * Connection: close
 *
 * See http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2.
 */
private static final boolean allowRestrictedHeaders;
private static final Set<String> restrictedHeaderSet;
private static final String[] restrictedHeaders = {
    /* Restricted by XMLHttpRequest2 */
    //"Accept-Charset",
    //"Accept-Encoding",
    "Access-Control-Request-Headers",
    "Access-Control-Request-Method",
    "Connection", /* close is allowed */
    "Content-Length",
    //"Cookie",
    //"Cookie2",
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding",
    //"Date",
    //"Expect",
    "Host",
    "Keep-Alive",
    "Origin",
    // "Referer",
    // "TE",
    "Trailer",
    "Transfer-Encoding",
    "Upgrade",
    //"User-Agent",
    "Via"
};
```

You have two options how to handle this situation:

1. With the default Jersey client you need to set a system property

   ```
   -Dsun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true
   ```

   which suppresses removing restricted headers from the request.
2. Use [ApacheHttpClient](http://java.net/projects/jersey/sources/svn/content/tags/jersey-1.15/jersey/contribs/jersey-apache-client/src/main/java/com/sun/jersey/client/apache/ApacheHttpClient.java?rev=5805)/[ApacheHttpClient4](http://java.net/projects/jersey/sources/svn/content/tags/jersey-1.15/jersey/contribs/jersey-apache-client4/src/main/java/com/sun/jersey/client/apache4/ApacheHttpClient4.java?rev=5805) which doesn't seem to have this restriction. Simply add one of the following dependencies to your project:

   ```xml
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-apache-client</artifactId>
       <version>1.15</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

   or

   ```xml
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-apache-client4</artifactId>
       <version>1.15</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

   and then create your client like:

   ```java
   ApacheHttpClient.create(com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig);
   ```

   or

   ```java
   ApacheHttpClient4.create(com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig);
   ```

Comment: I was able to get this to work by approach #1.

I actually preferred #2, but I consistently received "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated" errors, despite following the instructions in: http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-730

Answer (score 9):

Or just set this property dynamically before setting your header (if you don't want to set it as global setting):

```
System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true");
```

Comment: This works for me - I was getting the same problem with Cxf web client (3.1.1) which uses HttpURLConnection to make requests.

Comment: Also worked for me - using Amazon Corretto 11 (OpenJDK) and Jersey Client 2.39.1.